# How to bind container's application file log with Kubernetes logs command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have developed a web microservice in Golang. I have used zap logger to log the application log in a file at location **/var/log/myapp/myapp.log**.

**I want to see log information in file myapp.log through below command:**

*#kubectl logs mayappPod*

But it is not working as by default STDOUT and STDERR output is redirected to kubectl logs command.

**So my question is what exactly I am supposed to do to see the /var/log/myapp/myapp.log log through kubectl logs command.**

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl logs` command just show you logs from container(s) you specified. And container got logs from `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

The recommended way is to setup your logging library to write logs to `STDOUT`. But as a workaround you can create symlink from `/var/log/myapp/myapp.log` to `/dev/stdout` in your docker container.

Another option is not use `kubectl logs` at all. You could copy this log file from your pod using `kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar` [see](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp)